# Trying to reference ambiguous column in subquery

Tags: json, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to build a JSON object keyed on the `children.id` column:

```
SELECT
  format('{%s}',
    string_agg(
      format(
        '%s:%s',
        to_json(children.id),
        row_to_json(t)
      ), ','
    ), ''
  )::json as json_object
FROM (
  SELECT 
    children.id,
    children.first_name,
    children.last_name,
    parents.id,
    parents.first_name,
    parents.last_name
  FROM  
    children 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    parents ON parents.id = children.parent_id 
  ORDER BY 
    LOWER(children.last_name), 
    LOWER(children.first_name)
) t
```

Which will return a result like

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": "1",
    "first_name": "Joe",
    ...
  }
}
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "children"
LINE 6:         to_json(children.id),
                    ^
```

I'm not sure where to put another reference to "children".

I don't want to resort to aliasing the id column e.g. `children.id AS child_id` because that ruins the output, i.e.:

```
{
  "1": {
    "child_id": "1", <----- NO GOOD
    "first_name": "Joe",
    ...
  }
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Unrelated, but: why aren't you using `json_agg()` and `json_build_object()` instead of nesting `format()` and `string_agg()` ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not that experienced with the json features yet.  Would that produce the same structure, and object keyed by each row's ID?

Answer (score 0):

The alias `children` is in the subquery.  You only have access to `t`.  Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT format('{%s}',
              string_agg(format('%s:%s', to_json(t.id), row_to_json(t)
-------------------------------------------------^
                               ), ','
                        ), ''
             )::json as json_object
. . .
```

In the subquery, you should have unique names:

```
SELECT children.id as child_id,
       children.first_name as child_first_name,
       children.last_name as child_last_name,
       parents.id as parent_id,
       parents.first_name as parent_first_name,
       parents.last_name as parent_last_name
```

I'm actually surprised Postgres doesn't generate a compilation error, as many other database would, with the duplicate column names in the subquery.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it tells me 't.id' is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery output contains 2 columns named `id`. And 2 columns
named `first_name` and `last_name`. Rename `parents` table columns and
then you can use `t.id` as `to_json()` parameter.

```
SELECT
  format('{%s}',
    string_agg(
      format(
        '%s:%s',
        to_json(t.id),
        row_to_json(t)
      ), ','
    ), ''
  )::json as json_object
FROM (
  SELECT
    children.id,
    children.first_name,
    children.last_name,
    parents.id AS parent_id,
    parents.first_name AS parent_first_name,
    parents.last_name AS parent_last_name
  FROM
    children
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    parents ON parents.id = children.parent_id
  ORDER BY
    LOWER(children.last_name),
    LOWER(children.first_name)
) t
```